# plotting 3 variables on a single plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Hi have an experiment which consists of three variables, and I would like to plot them all on a single plot.

This is my df:

```
AB <- data.frame(block=c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B" ),
  familiarity=c("fam", "fam", "unfam", "unfam" ),
  prime=c("P", "UP" ),
  RT=c("570.6929", "628.7446", "644.6268", "607.4312", "556.3581", "645.4821", "623.5624", "604.4113"))
```

Right now I can only break one of the variables into two separate plots, like this where A and B are the two levels of the third variable:

```
A <- AB[which(AB$block == "A"),]
B <- AB[which(AB$block == "B"),]

pa <- ggplot(data=A, aes(x=prime, y=RT, group=familiarity)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype=familiarity), size=1) +
  expand_limits(y=c(500,650))

pb <- ggplot(data=B, aes(x=prime, y=RT, group=familiarity)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype=familiarity), size=1) +
  expand_limits(y=c(500,650))
```

I would like to superimpose plot A over plot B, and have this third variables to be identified by color.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example including sample data.

Comment: Many, but it's very hard to help you without seeing what your data looks like. Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Can't you just replace the values in third column by the colors and plot it in 2D. Again an example of your data would be great.

Comment: @Heroka the question has been edited

Comment: @stevezissou that makes solving things easier. Talking about solutions, are you aware that the rate at which you accept answers is very low, without any indications why the provided answers weren't appropriate.

Comment: @Heroka, no I wasn't aware.

Comment: @stevezissou no worries. It's a thing to keep in mind. Some people like rep more than others, but it can put people off spending a lot of time on answers to your (well-received) questions.

Comment: @Heroka, thanks for letting me know, I wasn't aware of the accept option, I was always just voting them up.

Comment: @stevezissou again, no worries. It's also for archival purposes: the solution that bests fits the OP's problem (according to the OP) appears at the top so it's easy to find for other with the same problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
p_all <- ggplot(AB, aes(x=prime,y=RT,group=interaction(familiarity,block))) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype=familiarity,color=block))
```

[image]

Data used:

```
AB <- structure(list(block = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), familiarity = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), class = "factor", .Label = c("fam", 
"unfam")), prime = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L
), class = "factor", .Label = c("P", "UP")), RT = c(570.6929, 
628.7446, 644.6268, 607.4312, 556.3581, 645.4821, 623.5624, 604.4113
)), .Names = c("block", "familiarity", "prime", "RT"), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you have different datasets for those variables, then you can specify the data

```
ggplot()+
  geom_line(data=A, aes(x=prime, y=RT, group=familiarity,linetype=familiarity), size=1) +
  geom_line(data=B, aes(x=prime, y=RT, group=familiarity,linetype=familiarity), size=1)+
  expand_limits(y=c(500,650))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need the two levels of the variable to be identified by color.